# Combine multiple fields into one and distinctly label in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I'm trying to combine multiple column values into 1 and then label them distinctly with a new column for a rollup table. Please see below for example.

Example:

```
(select
  id, size, size2
from
  table1
where
  date = curdate()
)a

union all

(select
  id, size, size2
from
  table2
where
  date = curdate()
)b
```

output:

ID   size  size2

1    23    47
2    25    33

How would I combine size and size2 into one column, and have another field that labels them?

Output would look like this:

ID    values    type

1    23    size

2    47    size2

3    25    size

4    33    size2

I'm thinking this should be some type of case statement, but I can't seem to wrap my mind around it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a 4 part union. New ids are interleaved from table1/2.ids:

```
(SELECT id*2+0, size,  'size'  FROM table1 WHERE date = curdate())
UNION ALL
(SELECT id*2+0, size2, 'size2' FROM table1 WHERE date = curdate())
UNION ALL
(SELECT id*2+1, size,  'size'  FROM table2 WHERE date = curdate())
UNION ALL
(SELECT id*2+1, size2, 'size2' FROM table2 WHERE date = curdate())
```